# Filter datagrid with calendar

Tags: .net, vb.net

I use a datagrid with rows columns with date format.

This is the datagrid creation code

```
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("tarea", "Tarea")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("horas", "Horas")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("descripcion", "Descripcion")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("fecha", "Fecha")
    dg_datos.Columns("fecha").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"


    dg_datos.Rows.Add("Ada Lovelace", "1", "desc.1", "10/11/2002")
    dg_datos.Rows.Add("Rafael Nadal", "1.4", "desc.2", "11/11/1822")
    dg_datos.Rows.Add("Lewis Hamilton", "0.4", "desc.3", "19/11/1978")
    dg_datos.Rows.Add("Charles Leclerc", "5", "desc.4", "02/01/1992")
    dg_datos.Rows.Add("HOLA HOLA", "5", "desc.5", "20/04/2022 0:00:00")





    Dim table As New DataTable
    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    dg_datos.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

```
        Private Sub Calendario_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles calendario.DateSelected


        BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("fecha = #{0:M/dd/yyyy}#", calendario.SelectionStart)

    End Sub
```

I dont know why this dont work

Comment: Why would binding a new, empty `DataTable` be of any use? You need to filter the `DataTable` that contains the data and is presumably already bound. You should adda `BindingSource` to your form in the designer, bind the populatred `DataTable` to that and the `BindingSource` to the grid, then set the `Filter` of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: Also, your formatting will fail on many systems because the standard short date format will vary. You should use this: `myBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("fecha = #{0:M/dd/yyyy}#", calendario.SelectionStart)`. If you're using a recent version of VB, use string interpolation: `myBindingSource.Filter = $"fecha = #{calendario.SelectionStart:M/dd/yyyy}#"`.

Comment: I have already used a link source, but I am unable to filter a datagrid by the selected date of a
calendar @John

Comment: There's no such thing as "a link source". If you have a `BindingSource` on your form and you have bound the data through it then you can filter the data if you do what I just told you to do. Of course you can't filter it with the code you posted because that does nothing to the data you already have. I told you what to do. Just do it. Maybe you should post the code you use to retrieve and bind the data in the first place, so that we can confirm that that is correct.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that the code you posted is even worse than I thought. You create a new, empty `DataTable`, but then you ignore it and create a new, empty `DataView` too and use that. Don't. Like I said, you need to filter the data you already have bound to the grid. If you bind the data via a `BindingSource` then setting the `Filter` of that `BindingSource`, just as I demonstrated, will work.

Comment: Private Sub Calendario_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles calendario.DateSelected


        BindingSource1.DataSource = dg_datos

        BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("fecha = #{0:dd/MM/yyyy}#", calendario.SelectionStart)



    End Sub                                                                                                                          @John Like this? or this is wrong too?

Comment: Where did I tell you to change the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource`? You do the binding when you retrieve the data and that's it! The binding is done. When you want to filter the data, all you do is filter the data. Do what I told you to do.

Comment: Sorry @John but im a begginer of .net and i dont control 100% the language, I do the bindingsource.datasource=dg_datos(is the datagrid to filter) but i dont understand you when you told me to dont change the datasource when i dont change, be patient please

Comment: You are changing it. That's literally what that line of code does. If you've already set the `DataSource` and then you set it to something else, how is that not changing it? Stop doing that. Do the one and only thing I told you to do, i.e. set the `Filter`.

Comment: @John I delete de dataview and the datatable i just create empty, now i link the datatable(dg_datos) to rhe new bindingsource, then i do the filter i dont work .                       Private Sub Calendario_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles calendario.DateSelected


        BindingSource1.DataSource = dg_datos

        BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("fecha = #{0:dd/MM/yyyy}#", calendario.SelectionStart)


    End Sub

Comment: The `DataTable` isn't just there for show. The idea is that you put the data into the `DataTable` and then bind that to the grid. That's how the data gets into the grid. As it is, there are no `Dates` in your data. It's all `Strings`. The format specifier you put on the column is pointless because there's nothing format. Populate a `DataTable` with actual `Dates`, then bind it to the grid, then sorting that data source will work. This is why you need to ALWAYS provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: @John I search a long of time to format the column to a DateTime, but the code i found dont work to my datagrid, i dont know why, i think i write bad, do yo know a any way to change the format to a Date Time??

Comment: I told you why it doesn't work: because there are no `Dates`. You can't format a `String`. It is what it is. If you expect to use a date format specifier then you have to provide a `Date` value to be formatted. This has really gone of track now and is not about the original question you asked. I suggest that you ask a new question specifically about populating the grid and we can address that. Once you populate the grid properly, the filtering will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just post an answer to avoid further agony, although there's no guarantee that you won't do things not in the answer. Anyway, you should be binding the data something like this:

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable

Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString)
    adapter.Fill(table)
End Using

BindingSource1.DataSource = table
DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

You then filter the data exactly as I have repeatedly told you in the comments:

```vb
Private Sub Calendario_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles calendario.DateSelected
    BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("fecha = #{0:M/dd/yyyy}#", calendario.SelectionStart)
End Sub
```

Comment: Okey I do properly like yo told me now, the error now is the name of the column, but i ckeck my code and the column name is like this "fecha", i think when a create the new table the data dont link properly, thanks for your time @Jhon

Comment: @Pablo, there's no problem with the table "linking properly". If you do it as I've shown, it will work. Obviously you have to use the correct column name when a column name is expected. The first thing that springs to mind is that your `fecha` column actually contains a date and time and you are providing just the date when you filter. If you do that then you'll only match records where the time is midnight. If you expect to match records with a range of times then you have to allow for that. Maybe the issue is something else but all we can do is guess with the information we have.

Comment: This is the creation of the column "fecha"         dg_datos.Columns.Add("fecha", "Fecha")
        dg_datos.Columns("fecha").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy" i think i have to define the time, and other thing, i dont use sql to link the table to the data, all the data is define in the code. If you need more information of the code, tell me and i'll show you @John

Comment: @Pablo, how you create the grid column is irrelevant to the data. That the data is displayed a particular way in the grid doesn't mean that that is exactly what's contained in the data source. I did suggest several hours ago that you show us the code that populates the grid. That seems an even better idea now. Please don't put it in a comment. Edit your question and provide all the relevant information, including the correctly formatted code snippet.

Comment: I just edit the code, i think there is some many errors ,I'm pretty lost @John